# Best image to convey 'Request Support'?

Tags: icons, image, customer-support

I'm working on a web application, one part of it has a table showing all the accounts a user has on a service, and allows them to click a button to request support with the account.

The icon is currently a small green circle containing a white plus symbol, which I think was possibly intended to convey a first aid kit, however it's not really clear, as it looks more like an 'Add New' sort of image.

I'm leaning towards finding a better image of a first aid kit, but I was wondering what Stack Exchange users would recommend based on their experiences.

Answer (score 3):

How about the a question mark combined with a person's head? (Sorry don't have example available and no time to look for it - my dog is barking for a walk).

The question mark is or was used as the help file icon and is generally used to convey there is information available about how to use something. The person's head would mean that you do not just have to read stuff, but can ask an actual person, either on the phone or through forum/webform.

Answer (score 2):

How about any of these:

[image]

http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=support

Comment: Thanks, that website is a godsend! The caveat is - and sorry I probably should have said this in the original post - it needs to be small, around 20x20px

Comment: Using the slider on top of the screen you can reduce the size of the icons and see if there's something you like.